# Dates in spanish App Engine Standard PHP 5.5

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

In my environment (App Engine Standard PHP 5.5) I have a problem with the language of the dates. I need to show them in Spanish, but I can not make it work.
In my local environment it is translated without problems, but in production it shows the dates in English.

In my php.ini I already put this:

```
date.timezone = "America / Argentina / Cordoba"
extension = "intl.so"
```

And in the code where I need to show the dates in Spanish (Argentina) I tried this:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_AR.UTF-8', 'es_AR', 'es-AR');
echo strftime("%d de %B", strtotime($event_date));
```

and in this way also:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8', 'es_ES', 'es-ES');
echo strftime("%d de %B", strtotime($event_date));
```

Am I doing something the wrong way?

Thank you very much